# Gatling/Scala - how to substring value from html response and use it in the next request?

Tags: gatling

I need to get CSRF token from this example page element

```
data-address-editor-options="{"changeBilling":true,"csrfToken":"07566cd8c8ef33a86b45b03e5f0a.2zBP36-ojP7OWTw5nvRINKjzldwKLzAQbkyA5grriJQ.iEQHsOzJ9La7Gl177IV6cveZ3o5wQHRcLwPMrnCR66CYRyeK5uX-iog9eQ"}"
```

and then in the next request in json body this token need to be used

```
def createBody(csrfToken: String, changeBilling: Boolean, changeShipping: Boolean): String = {
    """
      |{
      |"id": false,
      |"_csrf_token": """ + csrfToken +
      """,
        |"changeableAddresses":
          |{
          |"changeBilling": """ + changeBilling +
          """,
          |"changeShipping": """ + changeShipping +
          """
          |}
        |}
    """.stripMargin
  }
```

So the question is how to substring csrf token from 'string' value html response web element
**data-address-editor-options**
and then used it as a parameter to the function which create json body of the next POST request?

Gatling version 3.4.2

Please let me know if more information is required to answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, Gatling 3.4.2 is really outdated.
As of now, the latest version is 3.7.4 and it also supports Java and Kotlin for writing your tests.

Considering the Scala errors in your code (no offense meant), you're not a Scala developer, so one of those other options would definitely be a better choice for you.

> I need to get CSRF token from this example page element

Not sure how to understand it. Have you already gone through a first extraction to get this, or is it your full payload?

Anyway, the best solution for you is probably to use a [regex](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/check/#regex) check.

And then, for crafting the body of your next request (assuming Java 17):

```java
private static String createBody(String csrfToken, boolean changeBilling, boolean changeShipping) {
    return "{\"id\": false, \"_csrf_token\": \"" + csrfToken + "\", \"changeableAddresses\": { \"changeBilling\": " + changeBilling + "\", \"changeShipping\": " + changeShipping + "}}";
}

StringBody(session -> createBody(session.getString("token"), true, true))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
/** getting token */
val getToken: HttpRequestBuilder = http("getToken")
    .post(myHost + "/auth/main/token")
    .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    .formParam("username", "${username}")
    .formParam("password", "${password}")
    .formParam("client", "partners")
    .check(status.is(200))
    .check(regex("\"access_token\":\"(.+?)\"").saveAs("token"))

/** sending token */
val getApplications: HttpRequestBuilder = http("getApplications")
    .get(myHost + "/api/partners/applications")
    .header("Authorization", "Bearer ${token}")
    .check(status.is(200))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).